# Lite virtualization of processes

Tags: virtualization, sandbox, docker, lxc, openvz

I'm trying to figure out (if it is possible) how to run an user process in an insulated context (memory, network and other resources).

Let's assume that the program `x` is stored into a filesystem of an `host machine (h)`.
I would like to execute `x` in an insulated `hosted context (c)` (in other words, without creation of virtual hosted OSs).

The process elaborates output files into is context `c`. Then i would like to use those files into `h` context.

I heared about LXC, docker, dockerlite, openvz, etc. but it seems that one must create a *container* starting from an OS image.

So, shortly, is there a way to run `x` into `c` and get results (if any) into `h`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker you could create `c` (a container) and share a directory from the host (`h`) where you put your results from `x`. Please see the [volume docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-container-volume) on docs.docker.io.

`c` doesn't need to contain a full OS image. The `busybox` base container, for example, is about 2.5MB.

Comment: My question is: can `x` reside into `h` and be executed on `c`?

Comment: Yes. Once you share the volume from the host into the container `c` you can execute code `x` if it is on that volume.